# shortest path for travel

Tags: algorithm, optimization, shortest-path

Given connected line segments A->B->C->D (A->B is a line segment, then B->C is another and so on), how to find the minimum cost of traveling from A->D given the following options?

1. You can follow the line segments to travel, which costs you $1/unit_distance
2. You can 'jump' from some point on any line segment to some other point on some other line segment, which costs you $2/unit_distance covered in that 'jump' and then again choose between option #1 and option #2 for remaining journey.

The line segments are lines in 2D.

*e.g.* Suppose that you need to travel from (0,0)->(2,2)->(2,-2). There are many options to do this. I am listing 3 below:

1. If you follow option #1 entirely, the cost is 2√2 (from (0,0) to (2,2)) + 4 (from (2,2) to (2,-2))
2. If you jump from (0,0) to (2,-2), the distance covered is 2√2, and hence the cost is 4√2 ($2/unit for a jump).
3. However, a better minimum cost would result if you jump from (0,0) to (2,-1) and then follow option #1 from (2,-1) to (2,-2) which costs you 2√5 (for the jump) + 1 (for following option #1).

The number of line segments might vary. I was thinking about formulating some LPP for this, but unable to proceed any further. Can someone please help me in finding the minima for such problems?

Comment: Your example... could you break that out of a paragraph and into a form more easily digestible? I mean, where did `(2,-1)` come from? I thought there was just `0,0 2,2 -2,-2`...

Comment: Hi glowcoder, thanks for having a look at it. Like I mentioned, you can jump from a point on any line segment to any other point on any line segment (of course with penalty). I have also modified the example for better visibility.

Comment: Can you just create a separate weighted graph with all the possible edges and run a standard shortest path like Dijkstra's algorithm or A*?

Comment: Hello @Nabb, the minima could be on a non-integer co-ordinate, in which case Dijkstra's algo might not work, and I am not very good at A*, so I am not sure how it can help me (I mean what heuristics I can use and so on). Can you please provide me some links which can help me convert my problem in search problem using A*?

Comment: My first guess would be, that not all points within the line segments are relevant. Just going by intuition I would say, that in the optimal solution jumps always occur at places which are closest to each other in the line segments. If this assumption is true, you can find these points (there are O(n^2) many) and then build your weighted graph from there. Once you have a full weighted graph, you can use Dijkstra's algorithm. However you will need to prove the assumption I just made (probably a prove by contradiction).

Comment: @LiKao : Yes, that sounds good. Frankly, I am not good at theoretically proving things, but I will test it for some test cases to check its validity. Thank you. However, in the example which I posted originally, the point (2,-1) is not closest to the other line segment, which puzzles me (this point gives lesser cost path than the other two alternatives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't thing LPP can be used directly to solve the problem, because the distances are nonlinear, i.e. if you use as a distance measure for any point P on any of the line segments the distance from A following the line segments only, then the "hop" distance function that measures the cost of moving from a point P at distance x from A to another point P' at distance x' from A by "hopping", say Hop(x, x'), is nonlinear in both x and x' because the Euclidean distance metric is nonlinear.

However, let's assume first that there are only two segments (i.e. the path is A-B-C). The only possible pattern for a hop is to jump from the segment A-B to segment B-C, as it doesn't make sense to hop within a single segment. Let the three points be at coordinates A=(ax,ay), B=(bx,by) and C=(cx,cy). Consider then a point P on segment A-B and point P' on segment B-C so that the distance of P from A is d and the distance of P' from B is d'. The distance from P to P' through the segments is

```
d' + AB - d
```

where AB is the (constant) distance from A to B, and by hopping it is

```
2 * sqrt((x - x')^2 + (y - y')^2)
```

where

```
x =  ax + d  * (bx - ax) / AB
y =  ay + d  * (by - ay) / AB
x' = bx + d' * (cx - bx) / BC
y' = bx + d' * (cy - by) / BC
```

where BC is the distance from B to C.

The difference between the two distances is then

```
2 * sqrt((x - x') (x - x') + (y - y') (y - y')) - d' + AB + d
```

and I'm sure it can be solved for local minima by any standard techniques for such. The minima represent those pairs (P, P') where the benefit of the hop over following the segments can't be improved, and based on the geometry of the problem I'd really expect there to be only a finite number of such minimal pairs.

This same approach can be used on any pair of two segments on the path as the fact that the segments are connected was not used, so in this fashion you can build up an equivalent network with finite branching (as suggested in one of the comments above), and then use simple path-finding algorithm to calculate the optimal result.